# Robocopy script to move 7z files but if there are .log files copy those

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, copy, move, robocopy

I have a script (job A) that runs a Robocopy script to copy all uncompressed .log files from a number of machines each night. I have completed a process (job B) where the .log files are compressed into .7z files prior to job A. As many of the source machines will have a combination of .log and .7z files, I want to set the Robocopy job to move all .7z files to the destination but if there are no .7z files, I want the job to copy the .log files instead.

I have looked briefly at using the IF command but cannot see how to incorporate this fully. I am not sure that this is even possible.

The current job A script is below:

```
Robocopy "\\SOURCE\Logs" "\\DEST\Logs" /s /zb /r:2 /w:2 /eta /LOG+:\\DEST\\move.log /NP
rem Robocopy "\\SOURCE\Logs" "\\DEST\Logs" *.7z /mov /s /zb /r:2 /w:2 /eta /LOG+:\\DESTmove.log /NP

cls
```

echo  The copy process has finished

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to clarify, if there are only .7z files, move them. If there are not .7z files, copy (not move) .log files. If there are both .log and .7z files what should be done?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding - life got hectic! Anyway, if both are present, I just want to move the .7z files only, as in effect, the .7z files are actually the compressed versions of the .log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**  Here is an amended code using the robocopy lines you supplied in the comments and I added a filespec of `*.log` to the copy version.

It has not been tested.

```
@echo off
pushd "\\SOURCE\Logs"
if exist *.7z (
    Robocopy "\\SOURCE\Logs" "\\DEST\Logs" *.7z /mov /s /zb /r:2 /w:2 /eta /LOG+:\\DEST\move.log /NP
 ) else (
    Robocopy "\\SOURCE\Logs" "\\DEST\Logs" *.log /s /zb /r:2 /w:2 /eta /LOG+:\\DEST\move.log /NP
)
popd
pause
```

This is the kind of format you can use: add the two robocopy lines

```
cd /d "c:\folder"
if exist *.7z (
  echo move files
 ) else (
  echo copy files
)
```

Comment: @foxdrive So going off what I wrote as the robocopy commands, would it be... `code`cd /d "c:\folder"
if exist *.7z (Robocopy "\\SOURCE\Logs" "\\DEST\Logs" *.7z /mov /s /zb /r:2 /w:2 /eta /LOG+:\\DESTmove.log /NP
  echo move files
 ) else (Robocopy "\\SOURCE\Logs" "\\DEST\Logs" /s /zb /r:2 /w:2 /eta /LOG+:\\DEST\\move.log /NP
  echo copy files
)`code`